# Convert double to LSBF (little Endian) hexadecimal string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a double to a little-Endian hex string or directly to a specific type of long (see below).

Previously, I was converting a predefined little-Endian hex string to a long as follows.

`string hcommand = "01AC";
char * p;
long n = strtol(hcommand.c_str(), &p, 16);`

This worked as desired.

Now I am trying to EITHER convert a double to a hexadecimal string in little-Endian (least significant byte first) form (to then replace hcommand in the code above) OR convert directly from double to the same type of long as seen above.

I tried this, it does not process the same as above.

`double myDouble = 44033;
long hcommand = (long)_byteswap_ulong((int)myDouble);`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the results are identical once I convert _byteswap_ulong to _byteswap_ushort.

Comment: Yes.  I hope you understand *why* =)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're looking at only two out of four bytes.

In your first example, you get the value 0xAC01 (428).

In your second example, you take `myDouble` which is 0x01AC0000 and turn it into 0x0000AC01 (28049408).

If you want only one word of this, then use `_byteswap_ushort((unsigned short)myDouble)`.